# Freeing or clearing created objects

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

I have 2 windows forms; **Form1.cs** and **Form2.cs**.

Here are the code for **Form1.cs** in which will show the **Form2.cs** and Hide the the current **Form1.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Here are the code for **Form2.cs** in which will show the **Form1.cs** and Hide the the current **Form2.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

I have monitored the memory usage of the application and I have noticed that the memory usage of the application is increasing every time I execute the code above.

Comment: Exactly, what is your question?

Comment: New - "produced, introduced, or discovered recently or now for the first time; not existing before."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating new forms on each button click, so you hold many instances in memory after clicking the buttons multiple times.

You're probably looking for [`this.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `this.Hide()`, as the former will close and dispose the current form while the latter will only hide it.

If you want to hide and re-show the forms, you need to keep a reference to the forms. There are a lot of considerations (should a form be instantiated only once, or each time it is requested? Should it be possible for multiple instances of the same form be opened? And so on) and possible patterns and (third-party) solutions (e.g. [Application Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html), [What is a proper way of building Winform apps with multiple “screens”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173721/what-is-a-proper-way-of-building-winform-apps-with-multiple-screens)).

One solution would be to simply create your own form registry where each form has a singleton:

```
public static class FormRegistry
{
    private static Lazy<Form1> _form1 = new Lazy<Form1>(() => new Form1());
    public static Form1 Form1 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _form1.Value;
        }
    }       
    private static Lazy<Form2> _form2 = new Lazy<Form2>(() => new Form2());
    public static Form2 Form2 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _form2.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in code, you can just do `FormRegistry.Form1.Show()`. Please note this code is a proof of concept with many issues and much room for improvement, but it's there to give you the general idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks, I'll have a study on this concept.